# Can't run Wildfly instead Tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, wildfly

I tried to use Wildfly server instead embedded Tomcat from Spring Boot but i got 404 error, but Tomcat is worked well! All decidions what i found is not work, and i can't undestand what's wrong. For example in log from Wildfly and Tomcat, printing from auth filter (request.getRequestURI()) is a same - /reports/api/system.

main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReportApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer{

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(ReportApplication.class);
    }
    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ReportApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/system")
public class SystemController {

    SystemService systemService;

    public SystemController(SystemService systemService) {
        this.systemService = systemService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<System> findAll() {
        return systemService.findAll();
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
<!--        <relativePath/> &lt;!&ndash; lookup parent from repository &ndash;&gt;-->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.aviasoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>reports</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    </properties>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <name>releases</name>
            <url>https://nexus.aviasoft.ru/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <name>snapshots</name>
            <url>https://nexus.aviasoft.ru/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.reactivestreams</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactive-streams</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.core.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <!--            <version>42.3.8</version>-->
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>5.6.9.Final</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.0.SP1</version>-->
<!--            <scope>provided</scope>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.1.1</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
                <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- NB! Set <version> to the latest released version of frontend-maven-plugin, like in README.md -->
                <version>1.9.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <workingDirectory>src/frontend</workingDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <!--configuration>
                        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
                </configuration-->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>install node and npm</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>install-node-and-npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- See https://nodejs.org/en/download/ for latest node and npm (lts) versions -->
                            <nodeVersion>v18.16.0</nodeVersion>
                            <npmVersion>9.6.6</npmVersion>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm install</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <!-- Optional configuration which provides for running any npm command -->
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>install</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>npm run build</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>npm</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <arguments>run build</arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>

                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I tried to recompile, check dependencies, use different versions wildfly

Comment: You're using old Spring Boot which relies on javafx. Current WildFly uses jakarta, so there seems at least an incompatibility here. Search for compatible versions, but newest WildFly and newest Spring Boot v3 should be compatible. That is the first thing you have to fix. Don't know if there are others, but start with that.

Comment: @Slevin Thank you so much, i did it. But i can't understand how similar project with same versions is working (Spring Boot 2.7.1, Java 8 and Wildfly 22) was writen before

Comment: Yes, problem is solved.